# bzr ignore for all executables files under Linux

Tags: bazaar

Is there a way to make bazaar to ignore all executable files under Linux? They don't have a particular extension, so I'm not able to accomplish this with regexp.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all your executables were under a certain directory, you can ignore the directory content (eg. `bzr ignore "mybindir/*"`). I realize this isn't exactly what you want, but other than bialix's work around I don't think there is a better answer at the moment. It might be possible in future to add a keyword like `EXECUTABLE:` to the `.bzrignore` file which will indicate what you need. Even better would be to be able to chain them eg. `EXECUTABLE:RE:someprefix.+` .

Answer (score 2):

According to `bzr ignore -h` there is no pattern to select executable files.

But you can ignore them one by one.

```
find . -type f -perm /111 -print0 | xargs -0 bzr ignore
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore all files *without* extension with following regex: `RE:\.?[^.]+` but it will also ignore all directories and symlinks those don't have "extension", i.e. anything after dot.

Sometimes it's undesirable, so if you don't have a lot of executable files you'd better ignore them by name.